# PL/SQL : Ignoring -942 EXCPETION issues - still bombs on PACKAGE Compilation

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a Procedure within a Package that I create a "Temporary" table for processing. I wrote code to IGNORE the -942 error  because at the end of the Procedure I drop the table.  Therefore when it runs again, the table wouldn't exist and it needs to ignore that error.

However, when I compile the code (without the table present) it still bombs on me even with the EXCEPTION logic claiming the "table does not exist" which is true, but I don't care.

What am I doing wrong?

```
--Temp Table Setup
V_TEMP_COUNT INT;
NO_SUCH_TABLE EXCEPTION;
PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT (NO_SUCH_TABLE, -942);

--Declare Record Types
REC_P170201 CUR_P170201%ROWTYPE;

BEGIN --[SP_LOAD_A_DEPARTMENT_PVSS]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--PART P17.01 INITIALIZE                                                                --
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT (*) INTO V_TEMP_COUNT 
    FROM USER_TABLES 
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = UPPER('F_DEPARTMENT_ADT');
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_SUCH_TABLE THEN
      NULL;
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
      RAISE;
  END;

-- other stuff

END SP_LOAD_A_DEPARTMENT_PVSS;
```

Comment: I doubt the error is caused by the code you posted, since there is no table in it... what is the line number of the error and is that this code ?
You can't reference an object that does not exist in pure pl/sql, that is why it is throwing the 942. You could use ``ÈXECUTE IMMEDIATE``` to work around it. But then again, this is just guessing because the code above is incomplete. Please provide a minimal reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). That shouldn't be to hard in this case.

Comment: Aside from the coding issues being addressed by others, you should not even be trying to create and drop "temporary" tables.  This is one of the big differences in 'best practice' between oracle and other rdbms - primarily MSSQL.  In oracle, what you want to do (outside of your procedure) is create a Global Temporary Table.  Every session that references a GTT gets its own copy, and the data exists only for the life of the session.  I leave it as an exercise for the student to further research "Oracle Global Temporary Table".

Comment: GTT - wow, didn't even think of this. I'm looking at this now and is defintely the better approach. I will build this out and reach out if I have any questions. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The following block of code will not raise the NO_SUCH_TABLE error when there is no table named F_DEPARTMENT_ADT

```
BEGIN
   SELECT COUNT (*) INTO V_TEMP_COUNT 
     FROM USER_TABLES 
   WHERE TABLE_NAME = UPPER('F_DEPARTMENT_ADT');
EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_SUCH_TABLE THEN
    NULL;
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    RAISE;
END;
```

That is because the query is asking the view USER_TABLES if there is a row whose table_name column value is UPPER('F_DEPARTMENT_DAT'). Instead of a NO_SUCH_TABLE error, the error you will get is a no data found err (ORA-1403).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot catch compilation errors. One way to handle the none existence of a table is to perform the SELECT-Statement as dynamic sql, so it does get compiled on runtime:

```sql
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT COUNT (*) FROM USER_TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = UPPER(''F_DEPARTMENT_ADT'')'
  INTO V_TEMP_COUNT;
```

But I think the code you posted is not the one that throws your error at compile time. It might be the declaration of `REC_P170201`. So in this case I would recommend you, to create your own record type with only the columns you need in your procedure and then just select the columns you need in the dynamic sql.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT COUNT (*) INTO V_TEMP_COUNT 
FROM USER_TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = UPPER('F_DEPARTMENT_ADT');
```

Is not going to fail if `F_DEPARTMENT_ADT` does not exist. It will either return a value into `V_TEMP_COUNT` of `0` or `1`. You will can use that to make decisions in the rest of your code.

If you need your code to actually use your table then it will need to be done in dynamic SQL so that the compilation of your PL/SQL is not dependent on the compilation of your SQL (which will sometimes fail).

Saying that, I 100% agree with EdStevens: you're after a global temporary table here.